# How do I have animation between transition using $location.path to Redirect in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-mobile

I am using AngularJS as my structure and backend and JqueryM for the UI.

I have used $location.path to redirect using ng-click. Is there a way I can use JQM data-transitions or Ng-animate to get the transition?

Answer (score 2):

I got a lot of this from the [ngAnimate](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/docs/api/ngAnimate) and [ngView](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView) documentation.

If you set up your animation in css...

```
.fade.ng-enter { transition:0.5s linear all; opacity:0; }
.fade.ng-enter.ng-enter-active { opacity:1; }
.fade.ng-leave { transition:0.0s linear all; opacity:1; }
.fade.ng-leave.ng-leave-active { opacity:0; }
```

and refer to the class within your `ng-view` element...

```
<div ng-view class="fade"></div>
```

and don't forget to include the animate library...

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
```

and add it to your module...

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate'])
```

Then your animation should work.

Here is a quick and dirty working example.  It also lives in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bQU9XB):

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="page-one.html"><div>PAGE ONE</div></script>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="page-two.html"><div>PAGE TWO</div></script>
  <script>
  angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate'])
    .controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$location', function ($scope, $location) {
        $scope.location = $location;
    }])
    .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/page-one', { templateUrl: 'page-one.html' })
      .when('/page-two', { templateUrl: 'page-two.html' })
    }]);
  </script>
<style>
.fade.ng-enter { transition:0.5s linear all; opacity:0; }
.fade.ng-enter.ng-enter-active { opacity:1; }
.fade.ng-leave { transition:0.0s linear all; opacity:1; }
.fade.ng-leave.ng-leave-active { opacity:0; }
</style>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MyController">
  <button ng-click="location.path('/page-one')">Page One</button>
  <button ng-click="location.path('/page-two')">Page Two</button>
  <div ng-view class="fade"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for your reply...

I have tried following however whenever i include the 
<div ng-view class="fade"></div> 
it crashes my application when i try to run the page. What are some possible reasons for this?

Comment: Check your browser console to see if there are any messages that might point you to the problem.  Also, try and see if the plunker version works.  If it does, it's probably a problem with your dev environment.  If it doesn't it's probably your browser.

Comment: Is it possible to apply the fade class to a child of `ngView` ? In my app when I do a $location, it only update an element in the entire app, and I wanted to fade in and out that area only. Is it possible ?